# Payment processor for DigitalNote (Cryptonote coin)?

Tags: cryptonote

Sorry if you feel this is not the right place for this question, but how I can integrate a payment processor onto a website for DigitalNote?

Websites like coinpayments.net require donations to support your coin, so how exactly can I add support for DigitalNote (and possibly XMR/Bytecoin in the future)?

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of a payment process for XDN.

One thing you could do is look at, say, https://github.com/TheKoziTwo/xmr-integration and modify it to support XDN. This might involve porting some Monero specific RPC calls, but most of it ought to be fine, since both Monero and XDN are Cryptonotes.

I would be wary of using a "pay for support" site, as some of them are scams, and others may drop you without further warning if they stop getting payments.